# image displayed inline with sifr3 text hidden

Tags: image, sifr, inline

When sifr is loaded, the images i have loading inline with the H3 tags are covered up: http://dearearth.net/eco_fabrics.html

I know this is a known issue. Any help? Thanks! (also, explain in detail when possible, please)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you are replacing an `<h3>` which contains an image? That won't work.